# Google maps API UI showing but contents are not loading; no error thrown, using VUE and API Key is used

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, vue2-google-maps

I am currently using Vue and Vue2-google-maps. When my webpage is loaded, the UI for Google Map shows up (Zoom buttom, full screen) and when I try to drag the map around the console shows that I am recieving information from Google's API. However, the actual map itself is blank and nothing is showing.

```
<GmapMap :center="{lat:10, lng:10}" :zoom="12" map-type-id="terrain" style="width:750px; height:750px" ></GmapMap>
```

Under my `main.js` of Vue, I have declared my API key and use GoogleMaps accordingly.

```
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load:{
    key:'REDACTED',
  }
});
```

I have ensured that my height and width are set to PX values, tried shaking the browser etc. I followed a separate tutorial that does not use Vue but those include a `<script>` tag inside the document html, which I am unable to do in Vue template as they are ignored. The console also does not show any errors at all.

I will appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had a CSS style for background color for all and that was overriding everything that Google Maps displayed. This style was in the `app.vue` **parent component** and I was troubleshooting in a **child component** hence I was unable to find the issue. Removing this `<style>` made everything work as normal again.

```
<style> 
*{
 background-color: aliceblue;
}
</style>
```